# Template for storing social user information

Tags: database, mongoose, passport.js, opensocial

I'm looking for a template for storing user information.

I'm using passportjs which does contain a very minimal [structure](http://passportjs.org/docs/profile), but I'd need it to cover much more information

They do mention *opensocial* and *Portable Contact*, but after digging into both, Portabe Contact is dead and Opensocial was transfered to W3C, but I couldn't find any similar reference.

I found this [piece](https://gist.github.com/mlconnor/6998351) to be in the same spirit of what I'm after, but it's not complete and present no references to the actual standards.

Comment: I didnt actually get what you want to achieve. Can you tell a bit more?

Comment: In 1 sentence, I'm after a standard DB schema for storing user information. As mentioned, there used to be such references, but they all seem dead now...